# .NET Mvc append to view

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

How to add specific javascript/html/string to returned view from mvc? Or how i can use HttpContext.Response.Write for appending, not for rewrite?

I want to add json serialized viewmodel as javascript for future binding.

Comment: please show the code what you are trying to do .

Comment: In MVC, you don't generally interact directly with the response. You just return a view result, the framework handles the rest. If you want something to be in a view, add it to your view.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Can you be more specific about what you are after ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do it, via javascript.
You need to add script tag after your view html and do whatever you want when document is loaded.
The serialized model can come by simple `Viewbag.ModelString`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         //your appendings here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

as @mason mentioned in MVC framework a view is responsible to generate html markup. it seems like you want to have JSON object in your client side scripts.
if it's true you must do as below.
in action responce you must send the model instance to view

```
return View("YourView",yourModel);
```

then in YourView.cshtml file

```
@model YourNamespace.YourModel
<script>
  var modelForBinding = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```